# Existence (and construction) of a convergent series

Tags: sequences-and-series, banach-spaces, divergent-series

Suppose $(b_n)$ is an unbounded (real or complex) sequence. Does there always exist some (absolutely) convergent series $\sum a_n$ such that $\sum |a_nb_n|$ (or better, $\sum a_nb_n$) diverges? If so, do we have an easy explicit construction for it?

I think the answer is yes by the Banach-Steinhaus theorem, but I can't find an explicit construction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can choose a subsequence $b_{n_k}$ such that $|b_{n_k}| > 2^k.$ Define $a_{n_k} = 1/[k^2\text { sgn }(b_{n_k})],$ $a_n = 0$ for all other $n.$ Then $\sum a_n$ converges (absolutely) and the $n_k$th partial sum of $\sum_n a_nb_n$ is

$$\sum_{j=1}^{k}a_{n_j}b_{n_j} > \sum_{j=1}^{k}\frac{2^j}{j^2} \to \infty.$$

Comment: What if $b_n$ is complex, (but not real)? Then how is sgn($b_n$) defined?

Comment: Is that $\frac{2^j}{j^2}$ in the last sum?

Comment: @coffeemath Good point, but you just take a suitable $e^{it}$ instead of sgn($b_{n_k}$).

Comment: @zhw +1 Neat solution.

Comment: @coffeemath If $z\in \mathbb C, z \ne 0,$ then $\text { sgn }(z) = z/|z|.$ I had it wrong in my original post (now corrected).

Comment: @almagest Yes, thanks, now corrected.

Comment: zhw: I get it, and +1.